# SqlCacheDependency problems when upload on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcachedependency

I used SqlCacheDependency  in my website and it works on localhost without problem. but when Upload it on server and restore my database it has following error:

```
 The SQL Server Service Broker for the current database is not enabled,
 and as a result query notifications are not supported.
 Please enable the Service Broker
 for this database if you wish to use notifications.
```

but i set it true and works good on localhost. how can i set `Broker true` on `plesk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that must enable broker on database on server with server administrator.